# ASP.NET Mvc Request.Url.Host in Helper method

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to convert a user control to a helper method in Asp.NET MVC. However I do not seem to be able to have access to Request.Url.Host how do I get the correct host.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HtmlHelper has a ViewContext property.  The ViewContext property has an HttpContext property.  You should be able to access the Request from there.

```
  public static string MyHelper( this HtmlHelper helper, ... )
  {
        var host = helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host;

        ...
  }
```

**Update**: you might also be interested in some code I wrote to [mock out the HtmlHelper](http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com/2009/10/mocking-htmlhelper-class-with.html) class for my extension tests.  You can find it on my blog: http://farm-fresh-code.blogspot.com.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host
```

Comment: That is the same as "Request.Url.Host", which is what he said he had no access to.